# Configure Tomcat Classloader to look at the enclosed jar file before other locations

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, classpath

Tomcat's default class loader enforces the following priority for class path ( [source](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) )

> - Bootstrap classes of your JVM
> - /WEB-INF/classes of your web application
> - /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application
> - **System class loader classes**
> - **Common class loader classes**

We can tweak it by enabling delegate in `context.xml`

```
<Loader delegate="true"/>
```

> - Bootstrap classes of your JVM
> - **System class loader classes**
> - **Common class loader classes**
> - /WEB-INF/classes of your web application
> - /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application

In both cases, the web application looks into the */WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application* after */WEB-INF/classes*.

This is troublesome for me because, I have 2 jars;

> **JAR 1**
>
> - DoSomethingCool.java
> - doSomething-bean.xml
> - doSomething-property.properties

And

> **JAR 2**
>
> - doSomething-bean.xml
> - doSomething-property.properties

For some reason, DoSomethingCool.java is picking spring bean definition from **JAR2 > doSomething-bean.xml** instead of its own.

Is it possible to configure tomcat classloader so that a class will look into its own JAR first before looking at other locations?

Comment: Tried to configure your .jar as [PreResource](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/resources.html)?

Comment: I guess it is a valid option but is there a way for the class to look at its own JAR before looking outside? **PreResources** are useful when I want one JAR to trump others but what if I have multiple conflicts between JARs? PreResource definition would be very long.